# Rule Precedence

Tags: replacement, options, rule

Do I understand the following correct ($R$ on-the-fly executable rules, $E$ expressions)? I assume MATHEMATICA uses an unification algorithm like I learnt it for e.g. PROLOG.

1. If $R_1$ was defined before $R_2$, $R_1$ is tried first on $E$ and $R_2$ at most after $R_1(E)$ was evaluated (maybe to $E$, since $R_1$ didn't "bite", so now $R_2(E)$ is tried; maybe to $R_1(E)$, but $R_1$ is tried again first on that).
2. When $R_1$ is tried on $E$, it goes from left to right. (If the rule is $AA\rightarrow B$, $AAA\rightarrow BA$.)

Especially 2. smells funny, but maybe my "counterexample" (I got $AB$, so to say) was the result of a longer evaluation with other rules applied inbetween. (Sorry, haven't saved that one to show. Also, much too opaque large set of rules.)

Comment: Do you ask about the difference in the order of application of rules in the case of options application as compared to replacement rules (in functions like `Replace`, `ReplaceAll`, etc.)?

Comment: A good introduction is here: https://www.mathprogramming-intro.org/book/chapterNode5.html, especially https://www.mathprogramming-intro.org/book/node149.html

Comment: @AlexeyPopkov: Ultimately, I want to use them as ```TransformationFunctions``` in ```Simplify```.

Comment: @HaukeReddmann I am not sure that `Simplify` cares too much about order/precedence of the individual `TransformationFunctions`. It will try to apply them in many different orders to different parts of the expression, and see which one gives the best result

Comment: @LukasLang: Actually, that property would be beneficial (the "depth" to which my system must calculate to find the simplification is not very high). I have a problem with the functions, though. Could you point me to a working example, with actual "personalized" functions (like length of argument sequence in my case)? The MATHEMATICA site example is useless for me.